# Parse json nested array into c# object

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I´m need to parse a json object into a c# class, my problem is that json object has a nested array and it´s throwing some errors when parsing.

I have tried a couple of options:
a) do foreach in the elements of nested array, and add them to a new array
b) parsing using json.deserialize

No success so far

```
These are my c# classes

public class itemPrediccion
    {
        public string ClavePartido { get; set; }
        public string Ganador { get; set; }
        public bool EsFavorito { get; set; }
    }

    public class Prediccion
    {
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
        public string IdUsuario { get; set; }
        public int Jornada { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<itemPrediccion> PrediccionesJornada { get; set; }
    }
```

An object of class "Prediccion" would contain a list of "itemPrediccion"

```
This is the json object that I want to parse to a "Prediccion" object

{
    "IdUsuario" : "user1", 
    "Jornada" : "1",
    "PrediccionesJornada" : [
        {
            "ClavePartido" : "AP2019J1P1",
            "Ganador": "Morelia",
            "EsFavorito": "false"
        },
        {
            "ClavePartido" : "AP2019J1P2",
            "Ganador": "Chivas",
            "EsFavorito": "false"
        },
        {
            "ClavePartido" : "AP2019J1P3",
            "Ganador": "Atlas",
            "EsFavorito": "true"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is how I´m trying to deserialize

```
string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);

Prediccion prediccionUsuario = new Prediccion {
                        IdUsuario = data.IdUsuario,
                        Jornada = data.Jornada,
                        PrediccionesJornada = data.PrediccionesJornada
                    };
```

Throws this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the non dynamic variant of the deserializer:

```
var result =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Prediccion>(requestBody);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!!